# How to set a background name together with a variable?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

. My problem is - how to convert this line to -

```
  relativelayout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level1); // to change level1.png dynamically to level2 or level3 .
```

wanted line

```
  relativelayout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level+myvariable);
```

Like this. How it can be done ? Please help me ! I am new to android programming .